# IBM MQ JMS - Trying to read multiple messages at a time

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to implement read ahead functionality for my client. They get a bunch of messages from IBM MQ Queues. Trying to read multiple messages at a time since they are non-persistent messages. I am unable to call the setReadAhead method provided by MQDestination.I tried finding any alternate way of doing this, but looks like no one uses ibm mq that much. Maybe I am doing it wrong. Using version ibm 9.1, and currently without the commented line in the code it reads messages one at a time.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

```
    void initMQConnection(String queueName) throws JMSException {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        factory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
        factory.setQueueManager(jms_property.getProperty(queueManager));
        factory.setHostName(jms_property.getProperty(host));
        factory.setPort(jms_property.getProperty(port));
        factory.setChannel(jms_property.getProperty(channel));

        QueueConnection qConn = factory.createQueueConnection(username, password);

        QueueSession session = qConn.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

        ((MQDestination) destination).setReadAheadAllowed(); // --> Unable to use this method (Cannot Resolve Method)

        MessageConsumer mc = session.createConsumer(destination);
        qConn.start();
    }
```

In the code where I am using messageConsumer, I call
 `mc.recieve(1000);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "read multiple messages at a time"? Are you saying that a call to `javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()` or `javax.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(Message)` should return/receive multiple messages instead of just one?

Comment: What `import` are you using for `MQDestination`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read/get only one message at a time, not multiple messages.

The read ahead feature enables underlying **MQ client library to receive multiple non-persistent messages and buffer in it's memory**. This is done to avoid MQ client making calls over the network to MQ server to receive one message at a time. The received messages are buffered in the MQ client memory and delivered one at a time to client application when a consumer.receive() call is made. Read more here on Read Ahead: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=application-using-read-ahead-in-client

ReadAhead is a IBM MQ speicific function. You will need to cast the JMS Destination to MQQueue type. For example:

```
((MQQueue) destination).setReadAheadAllowed();
```

I don't see what packages have been imported, it appears that `com.ibm.mq.MQDestination` has been imported. `setReadAheadAllowed` is not a member of  `com.ibm.mq.MQDestination` class. Instead it is a member of `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination` class.

Comment: The `destination` is _already_ being cast to `MQDestination` which supports [`setReadAheadAllowed()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQDestination.html#setReadAheadAllowed-int-).

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram - I don't see what packages have been imported, it appears that com.ibm.mq.MQDestination has been imported. setReadAheadAllowed is not a member of this com.ibm.mq.MQDestination class. It is member of com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination that you pointed out.

Comment: That's a good point. I think you should include these details in your answer. It would make it more complete and less confusing.

Comment: Thanks @Shashi and JustinBertram. I am using com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination and not com.ibm.mq.MQDestination. But I did search for the method in the class, and it's not a member. Is it because of the version that is being used or a casting issue? 
And to answer Justin, I am trying to improve the performance of the application, and since it is non-persistent messages, I thought read ahead is a good option. Currently using a consumer.recieve() method to read the messages and not a MessageListner

Comment: What version of client are you using? Read ahead feature was added in MQ version 7.

Comment: There was a version mismatch. Thank you for bringing that up. Missed checking that.

Comment: Great!. Do you mind accepting my answer? :)